# Getting first element of specific type from ArrayList

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

I have `ArrayList` of type `Animal`. This list contains 10 references to objects which are 3 Dogs, 3 Cats and 4 Birds. All three types( `Dog`, `Cat` and `Bird`) inherits from `Animal`. Order of animals

Is there more efficient way to get first `Cat` from list than iterating whole list and using `instanceof` operator?

Eg.

```
Cat cat = null;
for(Animal animal: animalsList){
   if( animal instanceof Cat){
       cat = animal;
       break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in terms of the operations that you need to perform, this is as fast as it gets: searching an `ArrayList` for a specific object is always linear (i.e. `O(n)`).

In terms of readability, however, you could improve upon this by hiding the search in a helper method that takes a list and a type, and finds the first occurrence of the item:

```
public static <E> E findFirst(List<E> list, Class<E> itemType) {
    for (E element : list) {
        if (itemType.isInstance(element)) {
            return element;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you need your search to go faster than that, you would need a different data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that constantly keeps track of first `Cat` object in the list.  Else wise this search is the most ***efficient*** way of getting the first `Cat` object from the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other prior knowledge of the location of the `Cat`s inside the array, or any other information about the array's makeup (e.g., all the `Dog`s come first, then the `Cat`s and lastly the `Bird`s), then no, there isn't a better way.